# Apply a function to a variable? JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example

```
var contents = 'some text';

function fileSave(path){
// I'll handle saving the file, but I need the file contents
}

contents.fileSave('index.html');
```

So when the function is fun on the contents variable, the function has access to the variable. Like how replace() works in JavaScript.

EX.

```
str.replace();
```

but in this case

```
contents.fileSave();
```

the variable is interchangeable, the function applies to any variable is attached too.

Sorry, newbie..

Comment: It's not a good practice - to add methods to base classes. How about modifying function's signature to `fileSave(contents, path)`?

Comment: What you are looking for is called OOP, which you can do in js, but you need to understand the concept in depth before going on to modify prototype definitions like the answers below suggest to use it effectively in my opinion. I would recommend reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: @zerkms: It's neither good nor bad. It's just another tool that's right for some situations, and not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add methods to all strings, you add it to `String.prototype`.

```
String.prototype.fileSave = function(path) {
    var str = this + "";
    // work with the string
    console.log(str, path);
};
```

Just  be aware of your environment. Extending the native prototypes could conflict with other code. You'll need to decide for yourself if it'll be an issue or not.

```
var contents = 'some text';

contents.fileSave('index.html'); // some text index.html
```

Comment: And I knew it would be just a matter of time before the developers who are afraid of their own shadows would start down voting. My answer states the warning that it could conflict with other code, but ***this is not a bad practice*** as long as you're informed. Noobs are afraid of it sometimes, but it can be *very* useful. Tools are tools. They are meant to be used. No tool is the right tool for every situation, but none of them should be discarded.

Comment: I feel like modifying `String` and `Number`'s prototypes aren't a problem. `Array` and `Object` on the other hand, have a more imposing effect...in loops (and maybe more that I'm not realizing). So to me, modifying `String` and `Number`'s prototype don't have an effect other than the fact that they may override or be overridden by other code that does the same thing. So what do you mean by "conflict with other code"? Or is that what you mean? And why do you do this: `var str = this + "";` ?

Comment: And I find it funny that most people just follow this rule of not modifying the prototype because they heard it once but don't **actually** understand why

Comment: @Ian: Yes, exactly. The conflicts are mainly issues of other code using the same property on the same prototype for a different purpose. Certainly `Object.prototype` has issues that would require greater attention of the developer. I don't mind `Array.prototype` so much, but I do understand that there are situations where it wouldn't be wise. The reason that I do `this + ""` is that if your code is not running in "strict mode", JavaScript converts the primitive string to its `String` object wrapper, which can cause unexpected results in one's code. This converts it back to a primitive.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for all that information. I wasn't sure if there a reason other than overriding/being overridden, so that makes sense. And I had no idea about the use of `+ ""`, so that's another good thing to know.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a better way to do it without modifying `String.prototype`

```
function fileEditor(path) {
    this.save = function(data) {
       // do something with path & data
    }
}
```

Usage would be,

```
var someFile = new fileEditor("index.html");
someFile.save("some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will attach the function newMethod to all String instances, you can do that for other types as well.

```
newMethod = function (signature) {...}
String.prototype.newMethod = newMethod
'a'.newMethod()
```

As noted by others this might not be the best way but I still think it might be interesting for you to understand how javascript works (well, at least to get started with the prototype  in javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Never edit a prototype of an object you do not own!
Solution 1: use a constructor function, to create a new object as lost source wrote
Solution 2: declare an object via object literal:

```
var content={
    text:"loremipsum",
    save:function(){ // do work here }
}
```

and via content.save() you save.

Comment: *"Never edit a prototype of an object you do not own!"* Never use broad and sweeping rules as though they apply to all situations. Never spread FUD. Never be uninformed about the tools you have available to you. Never count anything out... it could turn out to be the perfect solution for a specific case.